# MDM deployment of Testflight build?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, mdm

Is it possible to deploy a TestFlight build using MDM?

- We'd like to deploy the app for testing with a config file.
- We don't have the app in the App Store yet and want to control who can run it.
- We are using a standard developer account, not an enterprise developer account.

Thanks